# Limit of sequence $n!\left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the limit of
$$
\lim_{n\to +\infty} n!\left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n.
$$
I have shown that $u_{n+1}>u_n$, but I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: By [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),  $$\sqrt{2\pi n} \le n!\left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n \le e \sqrt{n}$$, so the limit is $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

By Stirling's approximation we have:

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

So we can make comparisons to get:

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} n!\left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \times \left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n$$

Merge the two $\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \times \left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n \rightarrow (1)^n$. Can you figure out what to do now?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=n!(e/n)^n$. You can see $a_{n+1}/a_{n}>e$, so $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n$ doesn't exit.